# protect hyphenated word from breaking

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
bbbb bbbb bbbb ddf hdfhdf hdfhfd hdfhdf ddfgdfg dgdfg ert we Cabibbo-Kobayashi-Maskawa matrix is equal to 1
\end{document}
```

The output is [image]

Breaking the word

> Cabibbo-Kobayashi-Maskawa

is not a good idea. Does hyphenation play a role in breaking and how can I protect this word from breaking?

Comment: hyphens are normally break points, you can protect them, e.g. with \mbox or with babel commands, but if you remove break points from such a large word, latex will have a hard time to break the line without creating an overfull box.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be a good idea?

Comment: @egreg, not appealing to a gourmet's exquisite taste

Comment: Would you prefer humongous spaces between words?

Comment: @egreg, for the sake of having a solution, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't want to break a long hyphenated word, this is something to do in the final edits, because the naive solution (`\mbox{Cabbibo-Kobayashi-Maskawa}`) is likely to cause more aesthetic trouble than it saves. At this point you'll have to decide whether to reword the sentence (or even an earlier part of the paragraph) for reasons purely of appearance.  That tweaking of the wording may be sufficient to fix the line breaking, or it may need to be combined with `\mbox{...}`.

I have used the `mbox` approach without having to edit on much shorter phrases (`\mbox{$c$-axis}`).  In this case it works well.  In your case the compound word is over 1/3 of a line; in a two-column document you'd really struggle to get the breaking reasonable with it `mbox`ed together.

The longest example in my thesis was `\mbox{x-positions}`; in papers I've only had to do this for even shorter strings (chemical formulae in physics papers set using normal text).  It's probably best to reserve such tuning for situations where the comprehension of the text depends on it.

Comment: You can use `$c$\nobreakdash-axis` if you load `amsmath`.

Comment: @egreg, yes, and I did load `amsmath` but I find the `mbox` approach easier to read in the source.  I should probably have written a macro for the "-axis" example as I discussed several, mention the *c*-axis quite a few times -- but this only came up in the final proofreading stage so I just fixed it the way I knew.